# How Silverstripe URLs work?

Tags: php, url-routing, silverstripe

I am new to Silverstripe Framework / CMS. I see `./mysite/code/Page.php` as controller and `./themes/simple/...` as template directory. I logged into the admin panel and added new `test` page. The menu appears on the website with the URL `http://example.com/test` and content is displayed.

So what I want to know is, how to access the new controller let say `Download.ss`. I want to access the URL `http://example.com/download/123/` without adding the new page `download` in admin panel. Thank you.

Comment: Which version of Silverstripe are you using? The preferred method of setting up new routing rules differs between 2.4.x and 3.0.x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, any files with a `.ss` extension are template files not controllers.

Create a new class in `mysite/code/Download.php` which extends `Controller`.

```
class Download extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        // Automatically handles URLs like http://example.com/Download
    }

    public function exampleaction() {
        // Automatically handles URLs like http://example.com/Download/exampleaction
    }
}
```

After that you'll want to add a new `routes.yml` file to the `mysite/_config` directory to specify that the `index` function on your new controller should handle calls to `http://example.com/download/123`.

```
---
Name: downloadrules
---
Director:
  rules:
    'download/$ID': Download
```

Now the '123' portion of your example URL will be accessible as `$this->request->param('ID')` within the `index` function.

Now you can do:

```
class Download extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $fileID = $this->request->param('ID');
        // Do your thing.
    }
}
```

Documentation for this stuff is at http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/director

Comment: Thank you Drzax, I got the idea now.

Comment: I created `template/Download.ss` for theming but it is not executing... What is issue?